# Running amd64 docker image on arm64

Tags: docker

I am trying to run a amd64 based docker image on my arm64 based host platform. However, when I try to do so (with docker run) I get the following error

Error:
standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error

Comment: Host os : 5.4.0-1045-aws #47-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 13 07:04:23 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you still need to compile the code for arm64 architecture and build your own docker file, then `docker run` it.

Comment: i have compiled the code and build docker image on amd64 architecture but want to run the same docker image on arm64 architecture. is this possible?

Comment: @VinayakBachhav you can use Docker buildx to build multi-arch image on amd64 and run it on the arm64 machine.

Comment: @GaganParmar i have already used buildx and resolved my issue. thanks for the suggestions.